# Userinput reaches sensitive sink due to insecure usage of addslashes() without quotes

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, addslashes

I'm using the PHP program RIPS (http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/) to scan my PHP scripts for vulnerabilities and it's coming back the the message

```
Userinput reaches sensitive sink due to insecure usage of addslashes() without quotes Userinput reaches sensitive sink due to insecure usage of addslashes() without quotes
```

What does it mean insecure usage of addslashes? how can I secure the code below?

```
47: mysql_query $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions_answers(PID, Name, Email, Question, Date) VALUES ('$product_ID', '$name', '$email', '$question', '$date') ") or mydie ("Error" . mysql_error() . " File: " . __FILE__ . " on line: " . __LINE__); 
4: $product_ID = addslashes($_GET['product_id']); 
38: $name = addslashes(strip_tags($name)); 
34: $name = ucwords($name); 
21: $name = '';  
5: $name = addslashes($_POST['name']); 
40: $email = addslashes(strip_tags($email)); 
14: $email = '';  
6: $email = addslashes($_POST['email']); 
39: $question = addslashes(strip_tags($question)); 
35: $question = ucfirst($question); 
7: $question = addslashes($_POST['question']); 
36: $date = time();
```

NOTE: this is the output from RIPS, note the line numbers it should be read from the bottom up really.

Answer (score 1):

`addslashes` is poor protection from injection.  Insteady, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.  Actually, you shouldn't use that either.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Does that mean rewriting the whole database connection, insert etc.. and the way my script interacts with the database?

Comment: @user1398287 if you want to change to PDO or mysqli you will probably have to make relatively major changes.  Using `mysql_real_escape_string` will just require you to change the name of the function called (i.e. from `addslashes`)

Comment: I wouldn't call addslashes "poor" in favor of mysql_real_escape_string, as most of time they act exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

It is very interesting feature of Stack Overflow, which is still waiting it's diligent researcher:

## Nobody never ever read the question body.

Due to "Fastest Gun in the West" problem, a common habit has been developed among participants, forming an algorithm like this:

1. Read the question title.
2. Locate *keywords* in it.
3. Search your *local knowledge base* for the most widespread platitude or superstition connected to this keyword.
4. Put them as answer.
5. Collect reputation points.

Ironically, it works. Most of time.
People who ask, seldom bother with minimal research, with their questions are all alike.
So, this keyword-based approach works pretty often.

However, sometimes here comes a question that require reading not title only but also question body.
Sometimes question body even **contains an answer**, for anyone who bother to read error messages:

> insecure usage of addslashes() **without quotes**

as simple as that. Nuw let's turn to the actual problem:

> how can I secure the code below?

## Use placeholders.

- the most common solution is [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)
- most convenient and secure one - [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), which actually lets you use placeholder for  *everything* you want to add into query dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

try to use **mysql_real_escape_string** instead **addslashes**.

Hope this will help.

cheers

Comment: looks like mysql_real_escape_string won't be around after PHP 5.5.0? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @user1398287 looks like mysql_real_escape_string is still around.